I suspect a former professor in the department led a smear campaign against my wife in retaliation for reporting him - can he be held acountable?
TL;DR: I strongly suspect a professor in my department led a campaign against my wife (who is an instructor) to discredit her amongst the students in retaliation for her reporting him for harassment. It has devastated her. He left the university a year ago to move to another university - is there anything I do to hold him accountable?
I'm a tenured professor at a public flagship university in the US and my wife is a lab instructor in the same department. At the time she started the job three years ago, another tenured professor (let's call him Prof. A) was the instructor of record for the lab course. From the beginning, he was openly hostile to her during lab presentations by challenging her when she asked questions to her students and making indirect comments to the students about how her assignments were meaningless or flawed in some way. It got so bad that we both complained to the department chair and he filed a report to HR about this behavior. Prof. A had also exhibited similar behavior to two other professors in the department and altogether this got him removed from the course.
Prof. A was extremely angry about being removed from the course. Unfortunately, he is one of those professors that the students love. They would hang around his office all day and he was like one of their friends. I've heard instances of him making disparaging comments about other faculty in the department to the students, which I suspect he does to make the students see him as some kind of savior. To say the least, he has some kind of psychological issue that makes him behave this way so that the students love him.
Anyway, after he was removed from the course another tenured faculty (Prof. B) replaced him as the instructor of record in the lab. Over the past 5 semesters, my wife has experienced a lot of disrespectful behavior from the students in the lab (some overt, some subtle). In general, she gives the students challenging assignments that make them have to think deeply about how to apply the concepts they learn in other courses to the lab experiments they are doing with her. Often, the students just don't bother to do the more difficult parts of the assignment and get bad grades as a result. She gets evaluations where students say things like she is the "worst human being ever" and just teaches the lab in order to make their lives miserable. This is far from the truth as she works very hard on the course in order to try to make it useful to the students.
At first, I thought it was just students being students but the other day I heard from my grad students (despite the fact she teaches an undergrad lab) that there are rumors going around the department that Prof. A had to correct my wife during a presentation. I know exactly what they are talking about and Prof. A was completely wrong in this instance. Unfortunately, the students believe him over her, partly I suspect because he is a white male tenured professor that they adore and she is a non-white foreign-born female instructor. Now I am starting to suspect that Prof. A has been carrying out a campaign to defame her amongst the students in retaliation for him getting thrown off the lab course.
Additionally, the new professor on the course (Prof. B) treats her with the same kind of disrespectful behavior during lab presentations, cutting her off whenever she is asking detailed questions to the students and making comments implying she doesn't know what she's talking about or that her assignments are useless. I know what she is saying and I know that she is correct, so this is not a legitimate case of Prof. B simply correcting her. Plus he only says this in front of the students, not privately to her. This is all making me start to think that Prof. A said something about my wife to Prof. B when he took over the course - something like "watch out for her".
So right now, I'm starting to put the pieces together and it looks like Prof. A has led a concerted campaign to discredit my wife amongst the students in retaliation for 'getting' him kicked off the course. This has had a tremendous impact on her mental health and she is still being subjected to this treatment from the students in the lab and Prof. B. It's been completely devastating for her.
I want to do something about it to hold Prof. A accountable, but he left the university over a year ago to go to another university. Is there anything that can be done now that he is gone? I'm sure he will just continue this kind of bullying at the new university and there will be new victims, so something needs to be done to stop him.

‘I'm sure he will just continue this kind of bullying at the new university and there will be new victims, so something needs to be done to stop him.’ Bless your heart, but this sounds like rationalization of revenge, or at least it might seem that way to the professor.

I do not see a lot of undisputed, verifiable facts in your story. Even supposing that "something needs to be done" and granting that the story as you told it is exactly what happened, it's not really clear to me that you have enough evidence (or indeed any evidence) to do anything. I am not saying this to dispute your account of things, but rather to point out that "this is all making me start to think that" such-and-such might have happened is not grounds for any kind of disciplinary action.

Yes, I won't disagree with you that I don't have any hard evidence other than circumstantial evidence. And I won't say that "revenge" has nothing to do with it (I'm human after all). But I would think that most cases involving harassment or bullying in the workplace are like this. Most bullies are smart enough not to do this kind of thing completely in the open. So I guess my question should really be "how should I proceed?" Should I really just do nothing at all despite the devastating consequences this has had on my wife?

The behavior by Prof. B can't be disputed and is undoubtedly a large part of why the students don't respect her. But there's obviously no way to prove that Prof. A had anything to do with the behavior of Prof. B. It just seems very unlikely that two professors would treat her the same way and I'm trying to rationalize it

Is this course for majors only or is it taken by people from other departments? I'm a bit surprised that the professor(s) are even in the lab presentations. Has she discussed her planned labs with professor B?

Yes, it's for majors only. There is an "instructor or record" that is in charge of the management of the overall course and individual instructors in charge of the individual experiments in the lab. In principle, the instructor of record is not supposed to interfere with the assignments given by the individual instructors. There are also other instructors in the lab on other experiments, but Prof. B only treats my wife this way.

@Johnson Right. I think the problem here is that these kinds of suspicions (of the "probably I can guess what might have happened but I don't really have evidence" variety) can imo only be handled informally using whatever social contacts you have (if you don't want to end up in a big mess). If you have strong personal contacts at the other university, you could try to leverage those and informally let them know about your experience with the professor (without aiming for any official consequences). But if you don't, I personally don't see how you can do much of anything.

I wish I had the time to carry out vendettas against new instructors. Not that I ever would, that sounds terrible.... but it would just be amazing to have that kind of time as a professor! The only real solution is to let it go. Your wife needs to work more closely with the Prof in charge and make sure expectations fully align. If your wife is consistently asking problems that do not align with the course design of the faculty in charge, she will always be vulnerable to poor reviews, and constant tension with the faculty in charge.

@R1NaNo this is a good point - even if the way the criticism is being given is unhelpful it's worth thinking about if there's anything valid within it.

Shouldn't this Q come from your wife?

I second Bryan Krause's answer that your wife needs to treat the student evaluations as a separate problem from Prof A.
I would add that you can also treat Prof B's behaviour as a separate problem from Prof A. The one currently causing problems for your wife seems to be Prof B, and the institution took this kind of behaviour seriously when it was Prof A. It may be worth talking to HR again and raising the problems with Prof B's behaviour, although your wife also needs to take into consideration the risk of being perceived as a complainer. If Prof B is widely liked then reporting him to HR is unfortunately more risky than if he's a known problem amongst faculty. If it's reached the level where Prof B is implying her assignments are useless in front of students then it might be necessary to involve HR either way.
She could also try talking directly to Prof B. She could tell him she wants to take his criticism seriously but it's difficult to take it on board when he does it in front of students. She could ask him for specifics on what he thinks the problems with her assignments are, and why he interrupts when she asks detailed questions. If she gives him a more productive way to address concerns with her it may cut down on the interruptions in class, and she may find out that there are good reasons for some of his criticisms even if they're not being presented constructively. (This will work a lot better if she does it before talking to HR - once you talk to HR the relationship will be probably be pretty much nuked.)

This sounds more to me like typical privileged behavior than any sort of smear campaign.
I'm very worried that you will make things much worse by pursuing this suspicion.
I'd give the students a bit more credit for being capable of making their own judgments (though also it is common for women to receive worse student reviews without any intervention by senior professors with a grudge; this makes reviews a problematic measure of instruction quality). If they're not finding the assignments useful, it might be fruitful to investigate why that is and either change the assignments or change the communication about their purpose.

It seems more likely to me that there would be two professors who are both just kind of assholes/sexist etc than that one professor is enacting a concerted smear campaign against someone at a university he no longer works at. However people do talk to each other and if Prof A and Prof B are friends Prof B may be influenced by Prof A. This doesn't change the advice either way though.
